# Episerver Commerce R2 SP2: Triple log information for each update in Application Log

Tags: episerver, commerce

I'm getting triple log information on our Episerver Commerce Application Log each time I update a product. Is there anywhere to find What are these lines coming from?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE0i9.png)

Comment: I have seen this before, I believe it was a workflow that was running multiple times that created the issue.